# Ensuring an async method fires after a callback

Tags: javascript, async-await, callback

I have an older javascript library with callbacks I'm using like so:

```
async function usingOldLibrary() {
   await someAsyncFunction()
   oldLibraryFunction()
   .on('start', input => {//do something})
   .on('end', async() => {//clean up})
}
```

In my 'main' function, it's all called like so:

```
async function main() {
 await usingOldLibrary()
 await doAnotherAsyncFunction()
}
```

```
main()
  .then(() => console.log('done'))
```

My problem: in `main()`, I call `usingOldLibrary()` and before the `.on('end')` callback fires  I've already called `doAnotherAsyncFunction()`, despite my use of `await`  in `main()`.

Obviously the timing / mixing of callbacks isn't respecting the async / await code, but I'm not sure how to make this older library and its callbacks work with it, if I can wrap a promise somewhere or what to ensure that `doAnotherAsyncFunction` happens after the callback is done?

Comment: Why is there a start event? Doesn't the task start when you call the old function? Is there a possibility that either of these  start/end events are triggered multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async functions returns a `Promise` by default, you can specify the resolve to be triggered inside the `.on('end')` like so:

```js
async function usingOldLibrary() {
  await someAsyncFunction()

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    oldLibraryFunction()
      .on('start', input => {//do something})
      .on('end', async() => {
         //clean up

         resolve()
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: The `async` keyword in the handler may be unnecessary